# The kernel of an antiderivation on an exterior algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, exterior-algebra

This is a simple algebraic question I feel I should be obvious, but maybe isn't.

Let $d'\colon V \twoheadrightarrow W$ be a surjective linear map of finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field of characteristic 0.

Write $\Lambda V$ for the exterior algebra on $V$ and define an antiderivation on the $\Lambda V$-module $\Lambda V \otimes (k \oplus W)$ by setting

$$d(k \otimes W) = d(k \otimes k) = 0,$$
$$d(v \otimes 1) = 1 \otimes d'v$$
and extending $d$ uniquely to a $k$-antiderivation.

Let $\hat V$ be the kernel of the restriction of $d$ to $V \otimes k$.

**I feel strongly that the kernel $\ker d$ should meet the factor $\Lambda V \otimes k$ in the exterior subalgebra $\Lambda \hat V \otimes k$**, but don't have a concrete reason why. It's clear $\Lambda\hat V \otimes k \subseteq \ker d$ but the converse is less clear.

I think a proof by contradiction might start with letting $n$ be minimal such that the kernel of $d$ on the subalgebra $\Lambda^n V \otimes k$ spanned by products of $n$ elements of $V$ is *not* contained in $\Lambda^n \hat V \otimes k$, finding a sum with the the minimum possible number of terms witnessing this failure ... and then somehow contradicting minimality. I'm not sure how one would proceed from this point.

1) **Is my feeling even right?**

2) **Where can I find a proof, if it's correct?**

3) **What's a counterexample, if it's wrong?**

In case it's of interest, my motivation for asking this question is that it's always the case that if $G$ is a compact connected Lie group and $K$ a closed subgroup, then in the Serre spectral sequence of the Borel fibration $G \to G/K \to BK$, the leftmost column of the $E_\infty$ page is an exterior algebra on a subspace of the space $PG \leq H^*(G)$ of primitives of $G$ (where $H^*(G) \cong \Lambda[PG]$. This means that the differentials $d_r$ in the spectral sequence act as in the question. But I believe this is usually proven by other means and wondered if there were a purely algebraic proof of this fact with no topology, Lie algebras, or indeed Hopf algebras involved.

Comment: You need to specify a $\Lambda V$-module structure on $W$, or else I don't know what you mean by a derivation with values in $W$.

Comment: Good point; thank you. I have attempted to edit the question into coherence.